# Xamarin.Forms application analytics tracking concerns

Tags: android, tracking, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to track my Xamarin.Forms application below details using App Center Analytics for enhance our application in the future.

1. Device API version.
2. Most visited page.
3. Time Spend per page.

Is this legal?
Can I publish my application to PlayStore with App Center Analytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are (just a few) use cases App Center Analytics was made for.

Tracking custom properties can be acheived through Custom Properties APIs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin#custom-events

Or you can use custom properties sdk-wise:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/xamarin#use-custom-properties

With those, you can track quite a plenty of information you need. Note the limits, though - 200 different events max, and up to 20 properties per event.

As for publishing application on PlayStore it's totally fine, since App Center is basically just an SDK.